# Integral of type $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How can I solve integral of types

(1) $\displaystyle \int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}}dx$

(2) $\displaystyle \int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^4-1}}dx$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find  $\int\frac1{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}}\mathrm dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/how-can-i-find-int-frac1-sqrt41x4-mathrm-dx)

Comment: The proposed duplicate only addresses one of these integrals. If anything, that should be the one closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the variable substitution in Lab Bhattacharjee's answer can be generalized to handle indefinite integrals of the form:
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+1}}$$

Let $y = \frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{x^n+1}}$, we have:

$$n y^{n-1} dy = \frac{n x^{n-1} dx}{(1+x^n)^2} \implies \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dx}{x(1+x^n)} = ( 1 - y^n)\frac{dx}{x} \implies \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{x^n+1}} = \frac{dy}{1-y^n}$$

Let $\zeta$ be a $n^{th}$ primitive root of $1$, we have:

$$\int\frac{dy}{1 - y^n} = -\int\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\zeta^k}{y - \zeta^k}\right]dy = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\zeta^k \log(1-\frac{y}{\zeta^k}) + C \tag{*}$$

For $n = 4$, R.H.S of (*) reduces to

$$\begin{align}
&-\frac14 \left( \log(1-y) - \log(1+y) + i \left[\log(1-\frac{y}{i}) - \log(1 + \frac{y}{i})\right]\right) + C \\
=&
\frac12 \left[ \frac12 \log(\frac{1+y}{1-y}) + \frac{1}{2i}\log(\frac{1+yi}{1-yi}) \right] + C\\
=&
\frac12 \left[ \frac12 \log(\frac{1+y}{1-y}) + \arctan(y) \right] + C
\end{align}$$

For other $n$, let $c_k = \cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$ and $s_k = \sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$.

When $n$ is even, (*) reduces to:

$$ \frac{1}{n} \log(\frac{1+y}{1-y}) - \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}
\left[ c_k \log( 1 + y^2 - 2 c_k y) - s_k \arctan(\frac{s_k y}{1 - c_k y})\right] + C
$$

When $n$ is odd, (*) reduces to:

$$ -\frac{1}{n} \log(1-y) - \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}
\left[ c_k \log( 1 + y^2 - 2 c_k y) - s_k \arctan(\frac{s_k y}{1 - c_k y})\right] + C
$$

Answer (score 14):

(1) Put $x=\sqrt{\tan t}\implies dx=\frac{\sec^2tdt}{2\sqrt{\tan t}}$ and $1+x^4=1+\tan^2t=\sec^2t$

So, $$\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^\frac14}=\int\frac{\sec^2tdt}{2\sqrt{\tan t}\sqrt{\sec t}}=\int\frac{dt}{2\cos t\sqrt{\sin t}}=\int\frac{\cos tdt}{2\cos^2t\sqrt{\sin t}}$$

Put $\sin t=y^2\implies \cos tdt=2ydy $

$$\int\frac{\cos tdt}{2\cos^2t\sqrt{\sin t}}=\int\frac{2ydy}{2(1-y^4)y}=\frac12\left(\int\frac{dy}{1-y^2}+\int\frac{dy}{1+y^2}\right)$$

$$=\frac12\left(\frac12\ln\left|\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right|+\arctan y\right)+C$$

where $y^4=\sin^2t=\frac1{1+\cot^2t}=\frac1{1+\frac1{x^4}}=\frac{x^4}{1+x^4}$

(2) should be handled similarly by putting $x=\sqrt{\sec t}$

Answer (score 7):

(2) $$\int \frac{dx}{(x^4-1)^\frac14}=\int\frac{dx}{x(1-\frac1{x^4})^\frac14}=\int\frac{x^4dx}{x^5(1-\frac1{x^4})^\frac14}$$

Let $1-\frac1{x^4}=y^4,4y^3dy=-4\frac{dx}{x^5}\implies \frac{dx}{x^5}=-y^3dy$ and $\frac1{x^4}=1-y^4\implies x^4=\frac1{1-y^4}$

$$\int\frac{x^4dx}{x^5(1-\frac1{x^4})^\frac14}$$
$$=\int\frac{-y^3dy}{(1-y^4)y}=\int\frac{y^2dy}{y^4-1}=\frac12\left(\frac{dy}{y^2-1}+\frac{dy}{1+y^2}\right)$$
$$=\frac12\left(\frac12\ln\left|\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right|+\arctan y\right)+C$$ where $y^4=1-\frac1{x^4}$

(1) should be handled similarly by putting $1+\frac1{x^4}=y^4$

Comment: no problem. Since (1) and (2) is so similar, there must be simple way to get (2) from (1)...

Comment: Hmm, the overall minus sign is off! $4 y^3 dy$ should be $4 \frac{dx}{x^5}$. No wonder I can't get (2) from (1) before. Now I'm happy.

Comment: To solve (2) using answer of (1), just substitute $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} t$ for variable $x$ in (2). This turn (2) into (1) which integrates over $t$. The result will be the one in another post with $y^4 = \frac{t^4}{1+t^4} = \frac{x^4}{x^4 - 1}$. That answer will be the same as one here (assume you have fixed the overall minus sign) after another variable substitution $y \mapsto \frac{1}{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these is elementary.  Maple and Mathematica express them using hypergeometric functions.

Comment: But Answer of Both Question  are Given In elementry form.

Comment: Should we understand there is an implication from the second sentence of this answer to the first sentence?

Comment: Another indication that the implementations of Risch's algorithm in Maple and Mathematica are not complete in the algebraic case!